# Making the segment with given length $\sqrt[3]{2}$?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

Using Pythagoras' Theorem we can make the segment with given length of Square root of natural numbers. For example the segment of given length
The square root of 2 is equal to the length of the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs of length 1.

[image]

Now how we can make the segment with given length $\sqrt[3]2$, the third root of $2$?

Thank you

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubling_the_cube) Wikipedia article might be helpful. Refer to the "Solutions via means other than compass and straightedge" section in that article.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to construct $2^\frac{1}{3}$ with a ruler and compass?

Comment: @bnosnehpets, the link I provided also contains a procedure for construction just using a marked ruler.

Comment: There is another construction by *origami* explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_paper_folding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from [Wantzel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Wantzel) that the cube root of $2$ cannot be constructed by ruler and compass.

You can construct it with other tools; a method that goes back to [Menaechmus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menaechmus) is by intersecting a parabola with a hyperbola.

With analytic geometry it's easier: consider the curves of equations $xy=2$ and $y=x^2$. Then the abscissa of the intersection point satisfies $x^3=2$ and so is the solution to your problem.

[image]